# SQL JOIN two tables and duplicate rows appear

Tags: sql

Looking for ideas as to why my **JOIN** statement duplicates rows. 
I have two tables and join them with **JOIN**, **LEFT** or **RIGHT** conditions. Now something interesting happens, even with no added data from the second table my rows from first table duplicate. So, in table 1 I have 3 rows and after any **JOIN** it goes to 9 (3 x 3 duplicates) and I only have data from table 1 in my **SELECT**.

I tried multiple selects including **GROUP BY** with no luck so far. Can you please direct me towards the root cause?

Comment: Your sub-query is invalid in several ways. Start with fixing it.

Comment: Don't you get an error using a comma after the `tb1` in the FROM clause?

Comment: Not looking for a code just for the direction. Please do not get bogged down with the code. If you can advise the general direction it will be the help I am after.

Comment: Have you tried `SELECT DISTINCT`?

Comment: Root cause: That's how `JOIN` works.

Comment: Please provide some sample data and your code. We can't provide direction for conceptual explanations. Based purely on what you've stated, I don't believe you. You either have data in your joined table, or your query is more complex then you are leading on. Sample data and code will help resolve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your not joining each row to just one row.

```
Table1         Table2

 a | b | c      x | y | z
---+---+---    ---+---+---
 1 | 2 | 3      1 | 2 | 6
 2 | 2 | 4      2 | 2 | 7
 3 | 2 | 5      3 | 2 | 8
```

To join these tables without duplicating you would use:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  Table1
INNER JOIN
  Table2
    ON  Table1.a = Table2.x
    AND Table1.b = Table2.y
```

If, however, I used the following, I'd get 9 rows...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  Table1
INNER JOIN
  Table2
    ON  Table1.a = Table2.x
```

This is because each row in Table1 would join to ***all three*** rows in Table2

```
 a | b | c | x | y | z
---+---+---+---+---+---

 1 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 6
 1 | 2 | 3 | 2 | 2 | 7
 1 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 2 | 8

 2 | 2 | 4 | 1 | 2 | 6
 2 | 2 | 4 | 2 | 2 | 7
 2 | 2 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 8

 3 | 2 | 5 | 1 | 2 | 6
 3 | 2 | 5 | 2 | 2 | 7
 3 | 2 | 5 | 3 | 2 | 8
```

It doesn't matter if I include any of Table2's columns in the `SELECT`, it's the `JOIN` that's the issue.

```
SELECT
  Table1.a,
  Table1.b,
  Table1.c
FROM
  Table1
INNER JOIN
  Table2
    ON  Table1.a = Table2.x
```

Will give...

```
 a | b | c
---+---+---

 1 | 2 | 3
 1 | 2 | 3
 1 | 2 | 3

 2 | 2 | 4
 2 | 2 | 4
 2 | 2 | 4

 3 | 2 | 5
 3 | 2 | 5
 3 | 2 | 5
```

A similar case is when you need to aggregate the data before you join the data.

```
Table1            Table2

 Month | Val      Month | Day | Sales
-------+-----    -------+-----+-------
   1   | 'X'        1   |  1  |   6
   2   | 'Y'        1   |  2  |   7
   3   | 'Z'        1   |  3  |   6

                    2   |  1  |   4
                    2   |  2  |   5
                    2   |  3  |   6

                    3   |  1  |   7
                    3   |  2  |   5
                    3   |  3  |   3
```

To join these table without duplication, Table2 needs aggregating to the same granularity as Table1.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  Table1
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT
    Month,
    SUM(sales)   AS sales
  FROM
    Table2
  GROUP BY
    month
)
  AS Table2Monthly
    ON Table2Monthly.month = Table1.month
```

Comment: Thank you MatBailie. As suspected the JOIN and its condition is the problem. I need to look for different links.

Answer (score 0):

With not too much information to work with, my guess is that you are joining a result from a select from table one. For each row you get result of three rows which makes it nine rows all together.

Keeping it simple

```
SELECT * from tb1 
LEFT JOIN tb2
 ON tb2_key = tb1._nui
```

should give you 3 rows.

```
SELECT * from tb1
JOIN tb2
 ON tb2_key = tb1._nui
```

Should give you 0 rows if tb2 is empty.